# Drupal: imagecache doesn't generate images

Tags: drupal, iis, drupal-6

So, I have a strange issue with Drupal imagecache.

When I upload an image, the image is correctly stored in a folder, but imagecache doesn't generate the other cached images.

1. It doesn't work anymore after I moved the website from development server to the production environment.
2. The production server is IIS7.
3. All the "files" subfolder have both write/read permissions, imagecache module is supposed to create folders inside "files" folder.
4. The GD toolkit is correctly enabled (in Drupal report, imagecache module is correctly enabled). It is php 5.2.

thanks

Comment: Does it not generate at all, or not generate when you first visit the page (when it should appear)?  I have a web server that has the touch function disabled, and it doesn't show images on the first page view, after which they will work.  Maybe this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Imagecache's [troubleshooting guide](http://drupal.org/node/224913) in the handbooks. In particular, check the logs for errors explaining where the process is breaking down.

Also, check the paths that are included in your pages and make sure they are still correct, now that you've moved the site to a production server. This [issue has some more tips](https://drupal.org/node/628130), specific to the path problem.

Finally, if none of that helps, check the issue queue. There are several [issues related to IIS](https://drupal.org/project/issues/imagecache?text=iis&status=All).

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time when I have an issue with imagecache not creating images it has something to do with file system permissions. Verify that your web server is able to write to all of the files/imagecache directories recursively.